# Run F# code in C# - (Like C# in C# using Roslyn)

Tags: c#, .net, f#, roslyn

Is there a way to run F# code in C#? I have written an app in C# - I'd like to provide it the ability to execute F#, read Record objects, enumerate lists from F#. What is the current solution for this? I know in the future there will be probably be a way to do this via an update to Roslyn. Also, curious how to run F# code in F#, currently. Is there a way to do that easily?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, you have to make the F# a library, and then call it from C#.  Since F# is just .NET, using the F# library is (mostly) just like using any other C# library.  You might want to look into [FSharpX](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) for this portion, however, as it provides some utilities to ease calling F# from C# and vice versa.

If you want to compile the F# dynamically from C#, you'll need to use the F# CodeDom implementation from the [F# Power Pack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/).  This will let you use CodeDom to compile F# on the fly, and then execute it from C#.

Note that Roslyn will not help here, even when it's released, as it won't support F# as a code model, only C# and VB.Net.  It would potentially be possible to use Roslyn to manipulate and compile C# from within F#, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the options that Reed already mentioned, there are a two other alternatives based on using the F# Interactive - you can either run it as a separate process or you could use the open-source release to reference it and call it directly (which is quite challenging, though).

So in summary, you have three options:

- You can start the `fsi.exe` process and evaluate F# code in the F# Interactive environment (by sending F# code to the process by standard input). The F# binding for MonoDevelop is a good example how to do this (see [InteractiveSession.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/monodevelop/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/Services/InteractiveSession.fs)).

  The only difficulty is communication between the two processes, but I think this should be doable using a .NET remoting (or WCF) channel between the two. You can also just read the standard output from F# Interactive, but that might be a bit too simple.
- You could use the open-source release of [F# compiler & tools](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) to reference relevant parts of the F# compiler and call them (as a library) to evaluate F# code. This would be the best option and it would give you pretty much the same options you get with interactive C# from Roslyn.

  Sadly, this is not quite an easy task - I was playing with the idea of doing this and I made some progress (I can share that), but it is not done yet. The idea is to take the source code of `fsi.exe` ([here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/fsharp/fsi)), remove all UI and turn it into a library.
- Using CodeDOM, you can invoke the F# compiler (`fsc.exe`) to compile F# code into a stand-alone application (or library), load it dynamically and run it. A disadvantage is that this will start a new instance of the compiler each time you use it and so it may be a bit slow (depends on your scenario)

Answer (score 10):

Since the question has been asked, there has been a lot of exciting development :-)

You can now do this really easily using the [F# Compiler Services](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) project:

> The F# compiler services package is a component derived from the F# compiler source code that exposes additional functionality for implementing F# language bindings, additional tools based on the compiler or refactoring tools. The package also includes F# interactive service that can be used for embedding F# scripting into your applications.